# The battle over Gliese 581 and Gliese 667C?

Tags: exoplanet

In 2014, Robertson et al. made a case that stellar activity is masquerading as planets ([here](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2014Sci...345..440R) and [here](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2014ApJ...793L..24R)) for these well-known systems. In both cases, they claim that the only real planets discovered so far are planets "b" and "c". In 2015, Anglada-Escude et al. questioned the methods of Robertson et al. ([here](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2015Sci...347.1080A)). Also in 2015, Brewer et al. suggested that there is evidence for multiple planets at Gliese 581 [here](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2015MNRAS.448.3206B) (note, I only have access to the abstract - fulltext is [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1501.06952.pdf)). Is there a direction that a majority of the professional community is leaning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going by multiple online exoplanet catalogues and a quick scan through the papers listed on the SIMBAD pages for the host stars:

### Gliese 581

At the time of writing, the Extrasolar Planets Encyclopaedia (http://exoplanet.eu), the NASA Exoplanet Archive (https://exoplanetarchive.ipac.caltech.edu) and the Exoplanet Orbit Database (http://exoplanets.org) are in agreement and list only three confirmed planets for this system: in order of increasing orbital period these are *e*, *b* and *c*. It's not just Robertson et al. claiming that *d* is an activity signal, see for example [Hatzes (2016)](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/?#abs/2016A%26A...585A.144H). The most recent RV study of the system I have seen is [Trifonov et al. (2018)](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/?#abs/2018A&A...609A.117T/abstract) who give a 3-planet solution, not sure whether they searched for evidence of a fourth.

Gliese 581 is known to host a debris disc with an inner edge around 25 AU ([Lestrade et al., 2012](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/?#abs/2012A%26A...548A..86L)), much further out than *c* (or indeed any of the claimed planets beyond *c*), so I wouldn't be too surprised if there are additional planets to be found.

### Gliese 667 C

This one's a bit less settled because it doesn't seem to have attracted so many studies. Extrasolar Planets Encyclopaedia lists 6 confirmed planets, the NASA Exoplanet Archive lists 5 (they don't have planet *d*), while the Exoplanet Orbit Database only lists 2 (*b* and *c*). Again it is not just Robertson et al. claiming that there are only two planets, there's also the study by [Feroz & Hobson (2014)](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/?#abs/2014MNRAS.437.3540F). The identification of planet *d* as being caused by the stellar rotation is supported by [Suárez Mascareño et al. (2017)](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/?#abs/2017MNRAS.468.4772S/abstract) which is probably why this one was removed from the NASA list. Planet *e* is at roughly 2/3 of the rotation period and so is also considered suspicious. There doesn't seem to be nearly as much discussion about the outer candidates *f* and *g*.

Hope that helps as a summary. More data would definitely be useful for these systems if there is going to be any consensus, particularly for Gliese 667 C.

**Update (June 2019)**: the [recent study posted on the arXiv by Tuomi et al.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.04644) brings back planet *d*, unfortunately they don't discuss this case in detail. Confusingly they also decided to swap the designations of planets *d* and *e* (at least they did in their tables, they kept the old name elsewhere in their text). They also include the 91-day planet *d* at Gliese 667C, also unfortunately without a detailed discussion.

Answer (score 0):

> The battle over Gliese 581 and Gliese 667C?
>
> Is there a direction that a majority of the professional community is leaning?

The [Exoplanets Team](http://exoplanet.eu/team/) maintains the "[Extrasolar Planets Encyclopaedia](http://exoplanet.eu/)" which is updated daily.

The UI is a bit fiddly on a mobile device but the raw data can be downloaded to desktop applications that are able to work with it. Links expire quickly so I can only post 'root URLs'.

If you use the variable `star_name="GJ 667 C"` for the search term on the webpage: http://exoplanet.eu/diagrams/ you can create this:

[image: Plot of GJ 667 C Planet's Mass and Radius]

Use the search bar at the URL: http://exoplanet.eu/catalog/ for this result:

[image: Catalog of GJ 667 C's Planets]

Wikipedia's information page on the: [Extrasolar Planets Encyclopaedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extrasolar_Planets_Encyclopaedia) website.

Comment: I checked ADS again today and it still looks like we need better data before there is a consensus for more than 3 planets orbiting GJ 581 and 2 planets orbiting GJ 667C. Other signals may be due to stellar effects.